# Thin Lens Methods and Object Perceived vs Literal Size

Tags: optics

When using the ray trace methodology to solve a given thin lens question, does the arrow (commonly used as the example object when tracing) represent the literal height of the object or the perceived height of the object relative to the lens? Refresher image below:
[image: a generic ray trace]
<sub>(source: [physics.sc.edu](http://boson.physics.sc.edu/%7Erjones/phys153/raytracelens.GIF))</sub>

Same for the equation methods. When using below equation for magnification, derived from the thin lens equation, does $h_0$ represent the the literal height of the object or the perceived height of the object relative to the lens?
$$
\frac{i}{o}=\frac{h_i}{h_o}
$$
Note: in the event that these aren't the standard notations, $i$ is the image's distance away from the lens, $o$ is the object's distance away from the lens, $h_i$ is the height of the image, and $h_o$ is the perceived or literal height of the object.

Comment: What is the difference between a literal and perceived height?  Are you talking about the object arrow or the image arrow?  The image arrow isn't "literal" at all.

Comment: Im talking about the object exclusively. The further away an object is, the smaller it appears to be. For our purposes, this would be the perceived height. The literal height would be just that, the literal height of the object regardless of perspective. 

Example: a 6 foot man might at 100 yards might be perceived by you eye, to only be an inch tall. His literal height is 6 feet. His perceived height is 1 inch. 

Which value would I use for the ray trace method, and which value would I use for the equation based method?

Comment: The perception of height is in your brain.  The image of the man projected by your eye lens onto your retina is tiny.  There is no fixed reference to say that something is perceived as one specific height or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by height relative to the lens.  Those dimensions are the actual heights of the object and image that you would measure with a meter stick.

Comment: "Example: a 6 foot man might at 100 yards might be perceived by you eye, to only be an inch tall. His literal height is 6 feet. His perceived height is 1 inch..." His height relative to the eye is one inch, but if the lens were closer to the man, maybe as part of an optical chain, the perceived height might 1.1 or 1.2 inches.

Comment: As @User58220 says, you put a piece of paper at the location of the image, you can measure the size of the arrow on the sheet with a meter stick.  It's height will be $h_i$.  If you move the lens, $o$ changes, so both $i$ and $h_i$ will change.  You mention "perceive" and "eye".  I'm wondering if you are confusing the image with whatever light enters your eye.  If so, forget about that. It adds more components to the system:  your eye's lens, and your retina.  Concern yourself only with what you can measure with a ruler.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the Answer of @garyp, the image height is an actual height.

In the diagram in the original question, it is assumed that the object is emitting light in all directions.  The lens focuses some of the light emitted by a particular point on the object to pass through a particular point in the image.  You could place a piece of graph-paper at the location of the image and see the size of the overall image on the paper.  You could put a piece of film at the image location, and measure the size of the image on the developed film....

In the case of a virtual image, the situation is a bit more complicated.  But, the result is the same.  If you could see a **real** object at the location of the virtual image, say a piece of graph paper, directly, while at the same time seeing the virtual image, they would be superimposed with no parallax. The size of the virtual image, as inferred from comparison with the real graph paper, would be as calculated...